# Control a LED with BUTTON on SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 board

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, gpio

I think that my question is a little bit dumb but i am really stuck in this problem.
I have an embedded **SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1** board which i build **Linux OS** image version 4.14 with **YOCTO** project.
Now i want to control a **RBG LED** using a push **BUTTON** existing both on the board.
They asked me to check for **GPIO drivers** if they are existing in my Linux Image, I don't know how to check, then to make the LED Lights when I push the Button.
For the moment i have only the PINS of the Led and the Button.
I don't know what i must do now.
Thank you for your help!

---

Comment: What you describe can be purely done in DTS (via leds-gpio, gpio-keys, using corresponding LED trigger).

Comment: I really didn't get your answer. Can you clarify please ?

Comment: You can see an example [here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/sparc/+/refs/heads/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-wb50n.dts) on how to handle buttons and leds as GPIOs. As Atmel board support is done by [meta-atmel](https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/), maybe rise an issue on their github ?

Comment: so I think that i have to modify DTS file for my linux kernel so that i can control sama5d27 board leds with the button ?

Comment: @0andriy Hello buddy please can you help me out please i am still stuck in this problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 Board LEDS using DEVICE-TREE file in linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578148/controlling-sama5d27-som1-ek1-board-leds-using-device-tree-file-in-linux-kernel)